# Peticion Async/await

Tags: javascript, facebook, async-await

Estoy teniendo un problema con una petición async/await

Estoy iniciando sesión pero con la api de facebook, Realmente todo bien  para el inicio de sesión, pero en una parte solicito permisos. Entre ellos son estos

```
 scope:['pages_show_list','ads_management','leads_retrieval','pages_read_engagement','pages_manage_metadata','pages_manage_ads','public_profile'],
```

Y es que el ejemplo de facebook que es este

```html
FB.login(function(response) {
  // handle the response
}, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});
```

Si lo hago así, funciona bien :)

pero resulta que, Uso el Async/Await. porque estoy esperando la respuesta. Exactamente también viene un token

Que necesito usar para hacer otra petición a Facebook
entonces ... de esa forma no me sirve

**¿Hay forma de transformar eso a una async/await?, El código de Facebook?**

miren, Yo lo hice así

```html
      const  {authResponse}  =  await new Promise(FB.login);
```

Y funciona, para esperar el token y usar más adelante, pero como se dan cuenta . No estoy incluyendo los Permisos (Scopes)

Lo hice igual de esta forma

```html
     const  {authResponse}  =  await new Promise(FB.login,{
                    scope:['pages_show_list'],
                });
```

pero no sirve, pues no pide los permisos. solo pide   lo básico. (Email,name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si creas tus propias promesas puedes salir de la función asíncrona cuando quieras, por ejemplo:

```
const myfunc = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            
            /* ... */
            
            resolve(true);
            
        }, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});
    });
};

const logged = await myfunc(); // true
```

Tienes buenos ejemplos en la documentación de [async function - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)